# CDs and DVDs won't play or burn in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: dvd

I am trying to burn an Iso image to DVD but when I put the disc in the tray and close it, Ubuntu won't recognise it. The same thing happens when I try to play music on a CD. There is a whirring noise, and a few lights flash. If someone can tell me what tests to run, I'll kindly oblige and hopefully sort it out.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: 1) First of all what program are you using to burn or to listen to music?
2) Does the same thing happen on other operating systems if you have them?
3) I think your CD/DVD drive is broken. If so, this is not Ubuntu specific question.

Comment: I am trying to burn the Iso image of Linux Mint Maya. I have checked the MD5sum and it is correct. I have tested various CDs too but they aren't recognised either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have a problem with your DVD player, newegg has cheap dvd players or burners and you can even get a blu-ray burner for $60 now

Comment: Ok thanks for your help both of you.. not what I was wanting to hear but, hey - it's Christmas soon! I know what I'll be getting now...